# Trigger Update - 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I need a trigger for when I Fize hum insert into the table " reserve" automatically add in Table Room The Current State .

A major issue is that I need to check if reserva.id E equal to quarto.id .

How can I check the condition WHERE The Field And Correspondent ?
Here's Some failed attempts codes .

```
CREATE TRIGGER OcuparQuarto
AFTER UPDATE OF id ON reserva
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE quarto
SET status='0'
WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;
```

or

```
Delimiter |
create trigger OcuparQuarto
after insert on reserva
for each ROW  
UPDATE quarto  
SET quarto.status = 0
FROM quarto
INNER JOIN reserva ON quarto.id = reserva.id 
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

[image]

Comment: reserve = reserva and room = quarto

Comment: your first trigger should do the job all you need to change `AFTER UPDATE OF id ON reserva` to `AFTER UPDATE ON reserva`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> begin
> ```
>
> if (new.status = 0) then update quarto set status = 0 where quarto.id
>   = new.quarto_id;
>
> elseif (new.status = 1) then update quarto set status = 1 where
>   quarto.id = new.quarto_id;
>
> elseif (new.status = 2) then update quarto set status = 0 where
>   quarto.id = new.quarto_id;
>
> elseif (new.status = 3) then update quarto set status = 1 where
>   quarto.id = new.quarto_id;
>
> end if; end

This Works! Thanks!